# nodejs export an object to a specific program

Tags: node.js, export

I'm writing a nodejs program where I want to export an object for a specific program, while making sure other programs won't have an access to that object.

There is a way to direct exporting to a specific program in nodejs ?

Example for my problem:

The is a file called a.js :

```
let firstVar = 100;
let secondVar = 200;

module.exports = {firstVar};
```

Right now, every js file that will use require('a.js') will have an access to firstVar.
I want to create a file called b.js that can have an access to secondVar as well.
How can I export secondVar only to b.js while making sure every other js file won't have an access to it.

I want to do it because I want to test a project of mine by creating a test file that apparently needs a certain variable that i intentionally does want to export to the rest of the js files.

Comment: Could you please describe the underlying problem you're trying to solve this way? This seems like an odd thing to want to do in Node.

Comment: Is the specific program already running when you need to pass the object, or is  sensible to start the program with the specific object given as command line arg?

Comment: Is the other program also a Node.js application?

Comment: I will give an example.

Answer (score 0):

(function () {let firstVar = 100; // will be private to a.js}());let secondVar = 200;module.exports = {firstVar};

Answer (score 0):

As someone else mentioned, this is a pretty odd thing to want to do, so it's something that you probably should only be doing in very limited scenarios. That said, it can be accomplished by looking at the filename of the requiring module:

```
if (module.parent && module.parent.filename.match(/some_file\.js$/)) {
    module.exports.yourSelectivelyExportedVariable = 'some value';
}
```

module.parent is null if the file is being run as a script, and will be set to an object describing the module from which this module was required otherwise. See [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_object) for more info.